# ReactJS how to update page after fetching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm new to ReactJS and I'm now trying to do an interactive comments section (taken from frontendmentor.io), but the App component just doesn't show what it's supposed to show

This is my `App` component:

```
function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getComm = async () => {
            await fetchData();
        };

        getComm();
    }, []);
    console.log(data);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const res = await fetch("db.json").then(async function (response) {
            const comm = await response.json();
            setData(comm);
            return comm;
        });
    };
    return (
        <Fragment>
            {data.length > 0 ? <Comments data={data} /> : "No Comments to Show"}
        </Fragment>
    );
}

export default App;
```

The `console.log(data)` logs two times:

- the first time it's an empty Array;
- the second time it's the Array with my datas inside.

As it follows:
[image: console.log(data)]

If I force the `App` to print the `Comments` it just says that cannot map through an undefined variable

[image: the error when displaying "Comments" component]

This is my `Comments` component:

```
function Comments({ data }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((c) => (
                <Comment key={c.id} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Comments;
```

I'm wondering why the page **still** displays `No Comments to Show` even if the log is correct

Comment: What is in your comments component?

Comment: Your screenshot shows that `data` is an object not an array, so it doesn't have a `length` or `map` property. Did you mean `data.comments`? You can't just ignore bits of your data structure and expect JS to guess which property you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cristian-Irimiea Have right about response get from fetch. Response is an a object and can't be iterate. You need to store in state the `comments` from response

But you have multiple errors:

1. Take a look how use [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). Your function `fetchData` looks bad.

```
// Your function
const fetchData = async () => {
        const res = await fetch("db.json").then(async function (response) {
            const comm = await response.json();
            setData(comm);
            return comm;
        });
    };

// How can refactor
// fetchData function have responsibility to only fetch data and return a json
const fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("./db.json");
  const body = await response.json();

  return body;
};
```

2. You are updating state inside fetch function but a good solution is update state then promise resolve:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // here we use .then to get promise response and update state
  fetchData().then((response) => setData(response.comments));
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial state of your `data` is an array.

After you fetch your data from the response you get an object. Changing state types is not a good practice. You should keep your `data` state as an array or  as an object.

Considering you will keep it as an array, you need use an array inside of `setData`.
Ex.

```
comm && Array.isArray(comm.comments) && setData(comm.comments);
```

As for your `Comments` component you should consider expecting an array not an object.

Ex.

```
function Comments(data) {
    return (
        <div>
            {data.map((c) => (
                <Comment key={c.id} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Comments;
```